# Powershell Batch file to execute .ps1 files in directories

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have a very good deployment method.

I currently execute `.sql` files using powershell and I write results out to a log file. Currently the batch file, `.ps1` file and the `.sql` files are all in the same directory.

I would like to have one batch file that executes Build 01 `.ps1` and when Build 01 `.ps1` finishes it executes Build 02 `.ps1` etc.

Sometimes I have 20 build folders to deploy and I am trying to avoid having to double click 20 `.bat` files.

I am new to PowerShell - I apologize if this is not clear please ask.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include "*.ps1" | % { & $_ }
```

To understand how it works, you can decompose this line into:

```
$allScripts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include "*.ps1" #Get all ps1 file under the current directory
foreach($script in $allScripts){
    & $script # run the script
}
```

A side note, the current directory is the directory where you ran the command. This is not the script directory itself (if you run the command from a script)

Comment: Each batch file contains this:
cd /d %~dp0
powershell.exe -File sp_script.ps1
pause

I just put Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include "*.ps1" | % { & $_ }
in the .bat file?  I am really new sorry.

Comment: What I write make the batch files useless. This powershell script will call all ps1 files.

Comment: If you want to specify a directory use Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -include "*.ps1"

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you strictly want a batch file instead of a script you could do something like:

```
Start "" /wait "powershell.exe . .\build01.ps1"
Start "" /wait "powershell.exe . .\build02.ps1"
Start "" /wait "powershell.exe . .\build03.ps1"
Start "" /wait "powershell.exe . .\build04.ps1"
```

To clarify, I am referring to a batch file as a file ending with the `.BAT` or `.CMD` extension. The above should run the `.PS1` scripts in order, waiting for each to finish before launching the next one. If you would prefer to call each batch file on its own from an additional batch file you would use the `CALL` command, such as:

```
CALL Batch01.bat
CALL Batch02.bat
CALL Batch03.bat
```

Comment: cd /d %~dp0
powershell.exe -File sp_script.ps1
pause